# Spring Mvc 3 hasErrors is always false

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have following class,

```
public class MarketPlace {

    @NotEmpty(message="This Template Name is required")
    @Size(max=50)
    private String templateName;

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName;
    }
}
```

With the following post method,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PublishApplication.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String PublishForm(@Valid MarketPlace m, BindingResult result, Map model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "PublishApplication";
    }
    return "PublishApplication";
}
```

But hasErrors is always false? why?
Is I need any further configuration?

Comment: Are you sending data that will cause a binding error in the MarketPlace object?  If not, hasErrors() will always, correctly, be false.

Comment: Yes I am sending the data for marketplace and they are correctly bound. It's only the validation which is not triggering

Comment: Put mvc:annotation-driven to the beginning of your xml config file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set annotations "On" in your spring-servlet by adding this: `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Don't forget to include also the namespace "mvc". It'll look something like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

add xlmns:mvc:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

add to xsi:schemaLocation:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: I had a similar error. This doesn't work. My question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886038/how-to-turn-on-annotation-driven-validation-in-spring-4

Answer (score 0):

Only add this to your spring XML to enable annotation support to controllers:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

it should work after that

Comment: I had a similar error. This doesn't work. My question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886038/how-to-turn-on-annotation-driven-validation-in-spring-4