# Spring 4 MVC Validation not working - BindingResult hasErrors is false

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am unit testing a Spring controllers post method (using `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc`), and I'm trying to confirm that when there are validation errors in the form it will send the view back to the form by checking the `BindingResult.hasErrors` method.

Here is my test

```
  @Test
  public void testFilterChannelProgrammesWhenChannelListAndGenreListAreEmptyAndProgNameIsTooLong() throws Exception {
    String progName = TestUtil.createStringWithLength(301);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/filter")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .param("progName", progName)
        .sessionAttr("filter", new ProgrammeSearchDTO())
        )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("api/filter"))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/api/filter.jsp"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("filter", "progName"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("filter", "genreIdList"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("filter", "channelIdList"))        
        .andExpect(model().attribute("filter", hasProperty("progName", is(progName))));

    verifyZeroInteractions(channelProgrammeServiceMock);
  }
```

Here is the DTO that the session attribute is bound to

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class ProgrammeSearchDTO {

  @NotEmpty
  private String[] channelIdList;

  @NotEmpty
  private String[] genreIdList;

  private String fromDateTime;
  private String toDateTime;

  @Length(max = 200)
  private String progName;

  private boolean subtitled;
  private boolean signed;
  private boolean film;

  public String[] getChannelIdList() {
    return channelIdList;
  }

  public String getFromDateTime() {
    return fromDateTime;
  }

  public String[] getGenreIdList() {
    return genreIdList;
  }  

  public String getProgName() {
    return progName;
  }

  public String getToDateTime() {
    return toDateTime;
  }

  public boolean isFilm() {
    return film;
  }

  public boolean isSigned() {
    return signed;
  }

  public boolean isSubtitled() {
    return subtitled;
  }

  public void setChannelIdList(String[] channelIdList) {
    this.channelIdList = channelIdList;
  }

  public void setFilm(boolean film) {
    this.film = film;
  }

  public void setFromDateTime(String fromDateTime) {
    this.fromDateTime = fromDateTime;
  }

  public void setGenreIdList(String[] genreIdList) {
    this.genreIdList = genreIdList;
  }

  public void setProgName(String progName) {
    this.progName = progName;
  }

  public void setSigned(boolean signed) {
    this.signed = signed;
  }

  public void setSubtitled(boolean subtitled) {
    this.subtitled = subtitled;
  }

  public void setToDateTime(String toDateTime) {
    this.toDateTime = toDateTime;
  }  


}
```

And the controller method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String filterChannelProgrammes(@Valid @ModelAttribute ProgrammeSearchDTO programmeSearchDTO, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      return "api/filter";
    }
    model.addAttribute("results", null);
    return "redirect:filterResults";
  }
```

For this test the `return "api/filter";` should be actioned, but `hasErrors()` is always false. I have also tried with the following

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String filterChannelProgrammes(@Valid @ModelAttribute("filter") ProgrammeSearchDTO programmeSearchDTO, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      return "api/filter";
    }
    model.addAttribute("results", null);
    return "redirect:filterResults";
  }
```

But `hasErrors()` is still false

**EDIT**

After some more digging I have this sorted, it also required the following in the context config xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

And these dependencies in the maven pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Check this: [Result is always False.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527431/spring-mvc-3-haserrors-is-always-false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more digging I have this sorted, it also required the following in the context config xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

And these dependencies in the maven pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I got the same problem. I found that if validation error happened, the `@Controller` method did not execute at all